# magento2.1 paypal checkout fail when items having custom option

Tags: magento2, paypal

I found paypal failed with message "We can't place the order". This message shows after login your paypal account and redirect back to the order review page (even thought I disable it).

I'm wondering is there anyone else also having such problem? If so, what's the solution or any thread in github related to this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not caused by items's custom options. I had faced this type of problem before due to syntax error in any cart files or checkout files.

Check the log files. In log file you get error file name.

Comment: Hi paarth, thanks for your rely. I did check the log and found there is error about the product option. I will provide the details later. Could you please tell me how do you solve this. Actually there is an github issue already created and confirmed this to be an error.

Comment: Send me Email Id or Skype Id. I will tell you which files need to fix.

Comment: Could you post your solution here or any link to the solution? So this can also help other people who have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the same thing I'm facing which I've traced to this github post on the magento 2 repo

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4785